# ScrollView overlaps Text in VStack when hiding TabBar

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, tabview

Currently I'm developing a multi-tab app, therefore the `ContentView` consists of a `TabView`.
In the linked `SecondView` I want to hide the `TabBar` but when doing this, the contents of the `ScrollView` are overlapping with the content of the surrounding `VStack` below it.

The following code is a simplified and abstracted code of the app:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    static var tabBar: UITabBar!
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Text("Navigate")
                }
            }
            .tabItem { EmptyView() }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<50) { idx in
                    Text("\(idx)")
                }
            }
            Text("Just some text so visualize the overlapping")
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 30)
        .onAppear {
            ContentView.tabBar.isHidden = true
        }
        .padding(.bottom, -ContentView.tabBar.frame.height)
    }
}

extension UITabBar {
    override open func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        ContentView.tabBar = self
    }
}
```

To be more precise this starts happening after I apply the negative padding to the `VStack` in order to make the free space usable.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because by default `Text` view is transparent, so you just see scroll view content below it.

Here is a demo of possible solution

[image: demo]

```
VStack {
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(0..<50) { idx in
            Text("\(idx)")
        }
    }
    Text("Just some text so visualize the overlapping")
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
}
```

Another possible alternate is to clip ScrollView content

[image: demo]

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach(0..<50) { idx in
        Text("\(idx)")
    }
}
.clipped()
```

Comment: I already tried the fix with the background color but because the content is still behind the text it causes other problems. The '.clipped()' is a nice solution, now I'm wondering why I didn't came up with it myself. I guess the fact that this only happens if the negative padding is applied or the bottom padding of the text is below a certain number, confused me. Thank you