# ScrollView contents appearing outside of ScrollView frame

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I have a scrollview that contains a vertical stack of images.  I expected the images to appear entirely within the scrollview, but it appears there is a substantial amount of padding being added to the bottom, and the top images are cut off past the top of the frame.

In the demo below, I've made the scrollview background blue, and the VStack contains my images.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

[image]

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.vertical){
                VStack{
                    ForEach(samples, id: \.self) { sample in
                        if(sample.value(forKey: "asset") != nil){
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination:
                                    DetailView(sample: sample)){
                                        
                                        let uiImage = UIImage(data: sample.value(forKey: "asset") as! Data)
                                        Image(uiImage: uiImage!)
                                            .resizable()
                                            .scaledToFill()
                                            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                    }
                        }
                    }
                }// lazyvgrid
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                .frame(maxWidth: 200)
                .position(x: geometry.size.width * 0.7)
            }// scrollView
            .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.25))
            .frame(maxHeight: geometry.size.height)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
            .onAppear(perform: loadSamples)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a note - initializing `UIImage` in view bodies (and in `init`) is quite slow. A better method would be to create them in `onAppear`, to keep 60fps/120fps and prevent them from being recreated unnecessarily a lot of times. For some reason all the images look offset vertically, but that could just be the gif...

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62968961/12299030?